# Customer Community Profile cannot access users

Tags: apex, community

We are seeing the following error in our community where portal users check to view their account owners. I checked in the profile of community users and there is no place for them to vier users.

I am trying to remove this error:

> We couldn't find the record you're trying to access. It may have been
> deleted by another user, or there may have been a system error. Ask
> your administrator for help.

[image]

Comment: Is this [critical update](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lookup_names_perm.htm#:~:text=To%20activate%20this%20critical%20update,in%20Lookup%20Fields%2C%20click%20Activate.) activated early in your org?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Yes it is

Comment: So can you try enabling `View All Lookup Record Name` permission in your CCP?